# cycle containing distinct edges

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G$ be a $3$-connected graph with three distinct edges $e_1,e_2,e_3$.

How can it be proved that a cycle containing all three edges exists in $G$ if and only if:

(1) they aren't all incident with the same vertex.

(2) those do not, form an edge cut of the graph.

Comment: The wording of the Question was a little awkward, so I tried to edit it for clarity.  Please review my edit to ensure I did not change your intended meaning, and rollback my edit if I did.

Comment: It would improve the Question if you added your thoughts about how to attempt a proof, or about what makes the problem interesting.

Comment: @mathlover:  I'm not following the intent of your edits.  You removed the conjunction "and" connecting the two clauses, and you introduced a comma in the verb phrase "do not form".

Comment: @mathlover I get that you don't have enough reputation to comment on posts, but your suggested edits are better fit for comments rather than edits. Only the OP should be making such content changes to the question. Try looking for questions that you can answer or perhaps posting a question of your own to accrue some reputation :)